# Issue with Azure mobile service string/date column when queried by app

Tags: c#, date, datetime, azure

I have a Mobile Service on Azure and one of my columns (named InputDate) is set as type string. An example value is `2015-07-23T18:00:00Z` (ISO 8601 format)

However, when I query this table with the following code:

```
List<MyTable> MyTableData = await TheTable.Where(t => t.Name == "test")
                                          .OrderByDescending(t => t.__createdAt)
                                          .ToListAsync();
```

And then when I print out the date using:

```
Debug.WriteLine(MyTableData[MyTableData.Count-1].InputDate);
```

It looks like this `07/23/2015 18:00:00` which is a completely different format and doesn't include the T/Z separators and also leads to a `System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` exception when I call `DateTime.Parse` with the date as the argument.

I'm really not sure why this would be, I know I should probably have the column set as type date, but forgetting that it's a date, as a string it should display exactly as is in Azure, or at least that's what I would like to happen.

Comment: Does your `MyTable` class define `InputDate` as a `String` also? Or as a `DateTime`?

Comment: Yep its type is `string`

Comment: I could try using Wireshark or something to see what the raw response from Azure actually contains to see if it's something on the Azure end or indeed my app. Still totally stumped by this one!

Comment: Could you please include  TheTable Class

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the "DateTime" string property to a datetime with the  DateTime.ParseExact static function.

For example:
String strDate = "2015-07-23T18:00:00";
DateTime mydate = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);